# Is it possible to add multiple attribute values to a single attribute in a Magento product?

Tags: magento, enterprise

I have a basic product in Magento Enterprise (v1.11.2.0). I need to add 0 to many instruction sheets to this product. I know I could just hard code the links within a textbox and have them show on the page, but at some point, I'm going to need to access the value(s) for these attributes through the Magento API, so I need to break them out.

I know I could add multiple attributes to the set (ex. instruction-1, instruction-2, etc.), but that's not very clean or scalable.

I also know that I could add multiple "Custom Options", but something about that just doesn't seem right. If I come across a product that needs these custom options, that is really going to muddy up the user-facing view logic distinguishing between the two (actual custom options and faux custom options).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create one attribute called `instructions` as `varchar` in eav_attribute. Save all the data of instruction-1, instruction-2, etc.. in `instructions` attribute in serialized form. So, next time when you show the instructions, just unserialize them and you will be good to go.

Or are you looking something different?

Comment: Is there a way for that serialized data to be inserted via the Magento admin panel?

Comment: Yes there is a way. You need to give your custom `backend_model` for your new attribute `instructions`. `backend_model` allows you to edit the provided data before inserting it to the database, and also allows to prepare data before loading it. Confused? I will show you how to implement in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible depending on how much work you're willing to do.  I recently built a module with a many-to-one relationship and based it off of how tier pricing works.  I basically used a custom renderer looping through all the current values and inserting them into a table.  Then I used javascript to insert and delete rows.  If you copy the classes magento used for tier pricing, you shouldn't have too much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks, Nate, but I'm trying to stay within the bounds of the Magento framework, rather than building custom code. We may not have a choice with Magento, though.

Comment: Right.  I think if it was possible within the framework, the Magento team would have done it that way instead of the way described above.  I pretty much mimicked tier pricing when I did it.